# Cython: Convert memory view to NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, cython, memoryview

How to convert a typed memoryview to an NumPy array in cython? The docs have

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

numpy_array = np.asarray(<np.int32_t[:10, :10]> my_pointer)
```

I took this for my case

```
np.asarray(<np.float_t[:, :]> my_memview)
```

Using this the compiler tells me:

```
Can only create cython.array from pointer or array
```

Copying or not is not so decicive. I couldn't find any help on this.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should just be able to use `np.asarray` directly on the memoryview itself, so something like:

```
np.asarray(my_memview)
```

should work. For example if your cython source file contains this:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
def test(double[:,:] x):
    print type(x)
    print type(np.asarray(x))
```

Then after compiling it, you should be able to do the following from the python side:

```
a = np.random.normal(size=(5,5))
test(a)
```

Which produces the following output:

```
<type '_cython_magic_0182fca918bfa3618c3553e51b13e8ba._memoryviewslice'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Note: I'm using the cythonmagic extension for IPython.

Comment: Maybe it was too simple..  Compiles fine now. Would you check my [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978938/cython-should-i-use-np-float-t-rather-than-double-for-typed-memory-views)? I didn't dare to expand this one

Comment: does this not work for struct types? It returns a "TypeError: expected a readable buffer object"