# Cython: Should I use np.float_t rather than double for typed memory views

Tags: python, numpy, cython, typing, memoryview

Concerning memoryviews in cython, is there any advantage of typing a view with NumPy types such as `np.float_t` instead of simply do `double` if I'm working with numpy float arrays?

And should I type the `cdef` then the same way, doing e. g.

```
ctypedef np.float64_t np_float_t
...

@cython.profile(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cdef np_float_t mean_1d(np_float_t [:] v) nogil:
    cdef unsigned int n = v.shape[0]
    cdef np_float_t n_sum = 0.

    cdef Py_ssize_t i
    for i in range(n):
        n_sum += v[i]

    return n_sum / n
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you look in the numpy header file included with cython (e.g. in the master branch, it is [`__init__.pxd`](https://github.com/cython/cython/blob/master/Cython/Includes/numpy/__init__.pxd)), you'll find

```
    ctypedef double       npy_double
```

and

```
ctypedef npy_double     float_t
```

In other words, `float_t` *is* `double`, so there should be no advantange to using `np.float_t`.

Comment: I found it.. line 311/758 :| and as we are about usage of types: (Why / When) Is it preferable to use Py_ssize_t for indexing? (In the docs I just found '# Purists could use "Py_ssize_t" which is the proper Python type for array indices.') -> does that mean always when indexing NumPy/Cython-Array(s)/-views whatever..?

Comment: Instead of a comment, you should start a new question about using `Py_ssize_t`.  That will ensure it gets the most exposure.

Comment: You're right. Easier also to find for other answer seekers. Mostly I'm doubtful whether it's worth to make an independent question out of it. However, I'll endeavour to do so from now on

Comment: I made the Py_ssize_t thingy a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20987390/cython-why-when-is-it-preferable-to-use-py-ssize-t-for-indexing)

Comment: OK.  I was just about the comment here that the answer is "yes"--but it is hard to find a definitive statement of this.