# Convert C++ vector to numpy array in Cython without copying

Tags: python, c++, cython, numpy-ndarray

There is a C++ function that returns a vector of floats. How to convert this vector to NumPy array without copying? Now I'm doing this:

```
cdef np.ndarray arr = np.ascontiguousarray(cpp_vector, dtype=np.float)
return arr
```

but this works very slow (assume copying occurs) on large vectors.

Comment: The problem is, can you ensure, that the cpp_vector is long enough alive? Otherwise you will get dangling pointers in the numpy-array.

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/a/55959886/5769463

Comment: Note that the C++ standard doest not garantee that IEEE 754 format is used, even if it is the case with most (all ?) compilers. Should not it be a problem here?

Comment: Once you get buffer interface you can use https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.17.0/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html to get a numpy array without copying. If buffer interface is too much you can slightly change memory-nanny-approach from the first link to use std::vector. Btw with std::move (C++11) or std::swap (also C++98) you can change the owership of the data in std::vector.

Answer (score 0):

Casting the vector to float array and telling it to numpy should do the trick.

```
cdef float[::1] arr = <float [:cpp_vector.size()]>cpp_vector.data()
return arr

# arr is of type Memoryview. To cast into Numpy:
np_arr = np.asarray(arr)
```

The `[::1]` notation refers to a `Typed MemoryView` ([link](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html)). In the link you'll get more examples. We also use `np.asarray` to turn tne MemoryView into a numpy array (answered in SO [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20978377/cython-convert-memory-view-to-numpy-array)). The idea is to tell Cython to look at that memory space with a predefined format, avoiding any copying. Expanding from [this section](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy) of the docs named **Coertion to Numpy**:

> Memoryview (and array) objects can be coerced to a NumPy ndarray, without 
>   having to copy the data. You can e.g. do:

```
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np

numpy_array = np.asarray(<np.float_t[:10, :10]> my_pointer)
```

> Of course,
>   you are not restricted to using NumPy’s type (such as np.float_
>   here), you can use any usable type.
>
> Source:
>   https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#coercion-to-numpy

Comment: I get `Pointer base type does not match cython.array base type`. I think it is because vector has plain C `float`, but I'm trying to convert it to `np.float_t`. How to fix this?

Comment: plain C `float` might be equivalent to `np.float32` (32 bits) and not `np.float_` (64 bits). Play a bit with the output type and you should get it right.

Comment: Note: please modify or comment my answer when you get it right! We all want to learn how to do it.

Comment: I tried `cdef float[::1] arr = <float [:cpp_vector.size()]>cpp_vector.data(); return arr`, it returns `<MemoryView of 'array' object>` (it's OK). If I do `return np.asarray(arr)` I get `Segmentation fault`...

Comment: what about `return np.asarray(<float [:cpp_vector.size()]> cpp_vector)`

Comment: or use `np.asarray` outside of the function (once you have your MemoryView).

Comment: `cdef float[::1] arr = <float [:cpp_vector.size()]>cpp_vector.data()` works for getting MW, but when I wrap it by `np.asarray` (outside) I got Segmentation fault.

Comment: This has memory management issues - it doesn't link the lifetime of the vector to that of the numpy array

Comment: You are right! Any clue on how to solve it?

Comment: @ibarrond The vector needs to be held by a Python object. It could be in a `cdef class` (like in the duplicate I've suggested) or maybe it could be allocated using `new`, held by a [Cython array, then freed with `callback_free_data`](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html#cython-arrays) - although I haven't actually tested the latter approach. There's probably other options too