Coerce std::vector to NumPy in Cython's pure python mode
I want to convert a std::vector to an numpy.ndarray using Cython's pure Python mode. Using a .pyx file, I can achieve this using the following code [compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/59666408/6950750]:
import cython
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
from libcpp.vector cimport vector


def stdvec2np(vec: vector[cnp.int32_t]):
    return np.asanyarray(<cnp.int32_t[:vec.size()]> vec.data())


If I translate this to the following pure Python code, I receive errors.
import cython
import numpy as np
from cython.cimports.libcpp import vector
from cython.cimports import numpy as cnp


def stdvec2np(vec: vector[cnp.int32_t]):
    return np.asanyarray(cython.cast(cnp.int32_t[:vec.size()], vec.data()))

According to the Cython documentation, would assume this should be the correct for the pure Python mode.

The full error message is:
[1/1] Cythonizing coercion.py

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cython.cimports.libcpp import vector
from cython.cimports import numpy as cnp


def stdvec2np(vec: vector[cnp.int32_t]):
    return np.asanyarray(cython.cast(cnp.int32_t[:vec.size()], vec.data()))
                                                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

coercion.py:9:48: Not a type

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cython.cimports.libcpp import vector
from cython.cimports import numpy as cnp


def stdvec2np(vec: vector[cnp.int32_t]):
    return np.asanyarray(cython.cast(cnp.int32_t[:vec.size()], vec.data()))
                               ^
------------------------------------------------------------

coercion.py:9:31: 'cast' not a valid cython attribute or is being used incorrectly

Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
from cython.cimports.libcpp import vector
from cython.cimports import numpy as cnp


def stdvec2np(vec: vector[cnp.int32_t]):
    return np.asanyarray(cython.cast(cnp.int32_t[:vec.size()], vec.data()))
                                        ^
------------------------------------------------------------

coercion.py:9:40: 'int32_t' is not a constant, variable or function identifier
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/wehandre/workspace/code/cython_test/setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    ext_modules=cythonize(
  File "/home/wehandre/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
    cythonize_one(*args)
  File "/home/wehandre/mambaforge/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
    raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: coercion.py


Used versions: Python 3.10.6, NumPy 1.26.4, Cython 3.0.10
Used setup.py:
import numpy as np
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(
        Extension(
            "coercion",
            ["coercion.py"],
            include_dirs=[np.get_include()],
            define_macros=[("NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API", "NPY_1_7_API_VERSION")],
            language="c++",
        ),
        compiler_directives={"language_level": "3"},
    )
)

